# How to 'cast' to a generic object and execute method with generic parameter

Tags: java, android, generics

I have a class which initializes some GUI components when they are requested:

```
public class ComponentInitializer<T extends View>

public abstract void initialize(T object);
```

Now here is the snippet which initializes all components:

```
private <T extends View> void initComponents(View view) {
    // ArrayList<Component<? extends View>> this.componentInitializers
    for (ComponentInitializer<? extends View> initializer : this.componentInitializers) {
        View object = view.findViewById(initializer.getResourceId());

        if (object instanceof CheckBox) {
            ((ComponentInitializer<CheckBox>) initializer).initialize((CheckBox) object);
        }
        else if (object instanceof RadioButton) {
            ((ComponentInitializer<RadioButton>) initializer).initialize((RadioButton) object);
        }
        else if (object instanceof EditText) {
            ((ComponentInitializer<EditText>) initializer).initialize((EditText) object);
        }
    }
}
```

That works; I tested it.

But... There are numerous objects extending `android.view.View` and I'm too lazy to make a code block for each object extending `View`.

```
else if (object instanceof ObjectExtendingView) {
    ((ComponentInitializer<ObjectExtendingView>) initializer).initialize((ObjectExtendingView) object);
}
```

Is it somehow possible to decrease the code snippet to just an unary statement, just like something like this:

```
for (ComponentInitializer<? extends View> initializer : this.componentInitializers) {
    initializer.initialize(object); // Maybe with some casts
}
```

If yes, how? If not, what would be a workaround?

Comment: Have you considered using reflection and querying the object for the method you want to invoke? See: http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang.reflect/how-to-use-reflection-in-java.html Reflection is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing that `T` extends `View`, you can safely cast the object to `T`. Then the corresponding method will be called. This should work:

```
private <T extends View> void initComponents(T view) {
    for (ComponentInitializer<? extends View> initializer : this.componentInitializers) {
        T object = (T) view.findViewById(initializer.getResourceId());
        if (object != null) {
            ((ComponentInitializer<T>) initializer).initialize((T) object);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't immediately make sense to me. `T` is some specific type that is or extends `View`. Can you safely assume that `T.findViewById` returns a `T`? You're doing a number of unchecked casts here, so how do you justify them?

Comment: @PaulBellora: I cannot safely assume that `T.findViewById()` returns `T`, but I've often seen, even in tutorials, something like `T list = (T) T.findViewById(R.id.something)`, where the cast can't be assured either.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
private void initComponents(View view) {
    for (ComponentInitializer<? extends View> initializer : this.componentInitializers) {
        helper(initializer, view);
    }
}

private static <T extends View> void helper(ComponentInitializer<T> initializer, View view) {
        T object = (T)view.findViewById(initializer.getResourceId());
        initializer.initialize(object);
}
```